# Filtering out none values from a list. How does this code work?

Tags: python, iteration

I was searching how to filter None values out of a list and came on to this code.

```
my_list = [None, 1, 1, None]
print([x for x in my_list if x])
```

It works well, but there is no explanation on how the code works and I am not able to figure out.

Could anyone please explain how the code works?

Thank you.

Comment: This is wrong code to filter out `None`. This filters out zeros as well.

Comment: you need to read a little about [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), and know that `bool(None)` is `False`.

Answer (score 2):

As told in comments, this code filters out any falsy item (0, `False`, `None`).

You should explicitly tell what you need to filter out:

```
[x for x in my_list if x is not None]
```

Read [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 0):

Read about List Comprehensions [LIST COMPREHENSIONS](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python)

```
#this code only for understand purpose please write your own logic
my_list = [None, 1, 1, None]
#print([x for x in my_list if x])
l=[]
for x in my_list:
  if x:
    l.append(x)
print(l)
```

you can also use lambda or filter function